# Magento 2 admin path not working

Tags: magento2, admin, docker

I have setup an existing Magento 2 instance locally using a Docker(LAMP stack), which is working fine for store side but I haven't been able to get admin path working. It gives 404 page not found for **$PROJECT_PATH/admin** or **$PROJECT_PATH/index.php/admin**. I have tried all these things which I have found online to solve this but none of this has got it working:

- All row in `core_config_data` table for `path like '%base_url%'` is set to `$PROJECT_PATH`
- Clean URL is enabled and project path has `AllowOverride All` in apache config.
- Have `'backend' => array ('frontName' => 'admin')` in `env.php`
- Have ran `php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin"`

Can someone give me any pointers what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you access category and product pages?

Comment: @DavidDuong - Yes I can access product pages in store side, browse every other things, add product to cart, access checkout pages etc.